# how do i get the street address using getJSON foursquare venue API?

Tags: jquery, json, api, foursquare

Heres what the usual API json response looks like for venues
https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/explore#req=venues/search%3FproviderId%3Dnymag%26linkedId%3D59455

and this is the code i have so far

```
$.getJSON('https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search?ll=32.7153,-117.1564&limit=14&radius=1000&client_id=PKAHBB1OAX0B000CG5UUYO4BXV0LWQWKFB51EK3XVNFJ2ULS&client_secret=RDPX01C01RHCYASZIKVH5XXMPVFIPLFHFP1D53UR4GUWQD50&v=20120101',
function(data) {
console.log(data); 
    $.each(data.response.venues, function(i,venues){
        content = '<p>' + venues.name + '</p>';
        $(content).appendTo("#venues");

   });
```

});

But thats only grabbing the venues name. How do i also grab the address and Lat, Long, under the location section?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The address and lat/lon are actually exposed in the response you're getting from Foursquare. Try:

```
$.getJSON('https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search?ll=32.7153,-117.1564&limit=14&radius=1000&client_id=PKAHBB1OAX0B000CG5UUYO4BXV0LWQWKFB51EK3XVNFJ2ULS&client_secret=RDPX01C01RHCYASZIKVH5XXMPVFIPLFHFP1D53UR4GUWQD50&v=20120101',
function(data) {
console.log(data); 
    $.each(data.response.venues, function(i,venues){
        content = '<p>Name: ' + venues.name + 
            ' Address: ' + venues.location.address + 
            ' Lat/long: ' + venues.location.lat + ', ' + venues.location.lng + '</p>';
        $(content).appendTo("#venues");

   });
});
```